# How to transition UIToolbar with it's parent view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, transition, uitoolbar

How can I transition from one UIViewController (with bottom toolbar) to another one (without toolbar), so that while the animation is in progress, the toolbar moves away with the first view, meaning that the toolbar stays in it's initial position of the first view?

I've seen this behaviour in "Things" app.

Just to be clear, I am not looking for solutions such as hiding/showing the toolbar inside viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is a solution I wasn't very happy about, but at the moment it seems as the only one.

The point is to ignore the built in toolbar property of UINavigationController, create separate UIToolbar and place it inside your view controller.

```
// Create your bar items
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

NSArray *toolbarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: flexibleSpace, nil];
[flexibleSpace release], flexibleSpace = nil;

UIToolbar *customToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[customToolbar sizeToFit];
[customToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - customToolbar.frame.size.height, customToolbar.frame.size.width, customToolbar.frame.size.height)];
[customToolbar setItems:toolbarItems];
[[self view] addSubview:customToolbar];
[customToolbar release], customToolbar = nil;

[toolbarItems release], toolbarItems = nil;
```

This way the toolbar will slide away with it's view, causing no animation issue such as "white rectangles" or late appearing toolbar when placed in viewDidAppear...

Comment: I found this really helpful. A further tip: You can set up the toolbar items in the storyboard on the navigation controller's toolbar, even if that toolbar is hidden. Then you can just say: `[customToolbar setItems:self.toolbarItems];`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
- ( void )viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated
{
    NSArray            *items = ... UIBarButtonItem array...;

    [ super viewWillAppear: animated ];

    [ self setToolbarItems: items animated: animated ];

    ....
}
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't that clear. Your suggestion is related to toolbar items, not the toolbar itself, and it will preserve the toolbar on the second view. I want the toolbar to slide out together with the first view. So toolbar is visible on the first view but not the second view.